# Sign cordova ios app - provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to build and sign a cordova ios app without success.

I created a certificate, App ID and Provisioning profile (for distribution) in Apple Developer Portal.

Then I try to run:

```
cordova build ios --release --codeSignIdentity="XXX" --provisioningProfile="YYY"
```

But it says:

```
"no matching provisioning profiles found"
```

I've tried with both setting the path and UUID for the --provisioningProfile flag.

Very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: try adding `--device` to the command. Which cordova version are you using? I'll take a look in case there is some bug. I always use the build.json file approach http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#signing-an-app